# VSCode, why do i get error while trying to install mysqlclient to django project

Tags: python, mysql, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get my mysql integration to django project however when i try to `pip install mysqlclient`
VSCode throws this error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\popcorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\popcorn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yefz5w6i\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\popcorn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yefz5w6i\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\popcorn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f55ih7zv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\popcorn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yefz5w6i\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ic:\users\popcorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\popcorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.22.27905\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\popcorn\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\popcorn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yefz5w6i\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\popcorn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yefz5w6i\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\popcorn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f55ih7zv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the 
logs for full command output.
```

Anyone know how can i fix this? I've already installed  Microsoft Visual C++ pack version 14.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [latest release of mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#files) has wheels for Windows, but they are for 64-bit. If you're on a 64-bit install of Windows I would solve this by installing a 64-bit build of Python. Otherwise it seems to be a bug in the sdist where a header file was accidentally left out.

Comment: I installed 64-bit version of Python and it worked! Thanks a lot.